# Mocking an OAuth2AuthenticationToken from Spring Security in MockMvc tests

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-test-mvc

I'm using `@WithAnonymousUser` and `@WithMockUser` on my MockMvc tests but only `@WithAnonymousUser` is working as intended. I suspect that this is because I'm using Oauth2 differently from other solutions in Spring. I'm not using anything to do with UserDetails as far as I can tell. Instead, I'm using `OAuth2AuthenticationToken`. Spring is magically putting information from Google's oauth2 service into this token which I can pull out google's unique id ("sub") and then resolve that into a custom user class that I've created and store in JPA. I can't seem to find a way to inject google id or token into my tests. Any tips?

### build.gradle

These are my `build.gradle` dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.9.6'
    compile group: 'net.minidev', name: 'json-smart', version: '2.3'
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-security')
    compile('javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.0')
    compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client:5.0.5.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose:5.0.5.RELEASE')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql')
    testRuntime('com.h2database:h2')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
}
```

### PantryControllerMvcTest

This is my MockMvc test class. I'd eventually like to test drive my controllers with tests like these but I don't know what kind of annotation to put on my tests to mock out the `OAuth2AuthenticationToken` I use to validate my users. My only test that's failing is the last one called `shouldViewSettingsOk`.

```
package org.wecancodeit.pantryplus2electricboogaloo.controllers;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.redirectedUrlPattern;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithAnonymousUser;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class PantryControllerMvcTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    @WithAnonymousUser
    public void shouldViewIndexOk() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    @WithAnonymousUser
    public void shouldRedirectFromSettingsToLoginPage() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/settings")).andExpect(redirectedUrlPattern("**/oauth2/authorization/google"));
    }

    @Test
    @WithAnonymousUser
    public void shouldRedirectFromShoppingToLoginPage() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/shopping")).andExpect(redirectedUrlPattern("**/oauth2/authorization/google"));
    }

    @Test
    @WithAnonymousUser
    public void shouldRedirectFromCartToLoginPage() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/cart")).andExpect(redirectedUrlPattern("**/oauth2/authorization/google"));
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser
    public void shouldViewSettingsPageOk() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/settings")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

### PantryController

This is the controller I'm testing at the moment. As you can see I'm using the method `resolveUser(OAuth2AuthenticationToken token)` retrieve my user class, called `PantryUser`. That method comes from the abstract class `LoginController`.

```
package org.wecancodeit.pantryplus2electricboogaloo.controllers;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.wecancodeit.pantryplus2electricboogaloo.cart.Cart;
import org.wecancodeit.pantryplus2electricboogaloo.cart.CartRepository;
import org.wecancodeit.pantryplus2electricboogaloo.category.CategoryRepository;
import org.wecancodeit.pantryplus2electricboogaloo.user.PantryUser;
import org.wecancodeit.pantryplus2electricboogaloo.user.UserRepository;

@Controller
public class PantryController extends LoginController {

    @Resource
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepo;

    @Resource
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    @Resource
    private CartRepository cartRepo;

    @Resource
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping("/settings")
    public String displayUserForm(Model model, OAuth2AuthenticationToken token) {
        model.addAttribute("user", resolveUser(token));
        return "user-form";
    }

    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping("/shopping")
    public String displayShopping(Model model, OAuth2AuthenticationToken token) {
        model.addAttribute("categories", categoryRepo.findAll());
        PantryUser user = resolveUser(token);
        if(!user.isValid()) {
            return "redirect:/settings";
        }
        model.addAttribute("cart", user.getCart());

        return "shopping";
    }

    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping("/cart")
    public String displayCart(Model model, OAuth2AuthenticationToken token) {
        Cart cart = resolveUser(token).getCart();
        model.addAttribute("cart", cart);
        model.addAttribute("lineItems", cart.getLineItems());
        model.addAttribute("countedLineItems", cart.getCountedLineItems());
        return "cart";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/about-us")
    public String displayAboutUs() {
        return "about-us";
    }

    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String displayWelcomeView(Model model, OAuth2AuthenticationToken token) {
        boolean isAuthenticated = token != null;
        model.addAttribute("authenticated", isAuthenticated);
        if (isAuthenticated) {
            PantryUser user = resolveUser(token);
            if(!user.isValid()) {
                return "redirect:/settings";
            }
            model.addAttribute("user", user);
        }
        return "welcome";
    }

}
```

### LoginController

Here's the `LoginController` that's being extended by the previous controller class. It turns `OAuth2AuthenticationToken`'s into my `PantryUser`

```
package org.wecancodeit.pantryplus2electricboogaloo.controllers;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.user.OAuth2User;
import org.wecancodeit.pantryplus2electricboogaloo.user.PantryUser;
import org.wecancodeit.pantryplus2electricboogaloo.user.UserRepository;

public abstract class LoginController {

    @Resource
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    @Resource
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public PantryUser resolveUser(OAuth2AuthenticationToken token) {
        String googleName = getGoogleNameFrom(token);
        return userRepo.findByGoogleName(googleName).orElseGet(() -> {
            OAuth2User googleId = getGoogleId(token);
            userRepo.save(new PantryUser(googleId));
            entityManager.flush();
            entityManager.clear();
            return userRepo.findByGoogleName(googleName).get();
        });
    }

    private String getGoogleNameFrom(OAuth2AuthenticationToken token) {
        return (String) getGoogleId(token).getAttributes().get("sub");
    }

    private OAuth2User getGoogleId(OAuth2AuthenticationToken token) {
        return token.getPrincipal();
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you eventually solve this? @AlexM

Comment: I have not but on seeing this problem again I would try hosting my project locally, hit an endpoint and examine the request that is received with a debugger. The request would hopefully have Google's secret sauce in it. If it did there's the additional issue of then sending a mock request in a test but someone may have done that before. @IntegralMaster

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to this as well.  In my case, the OAuth provider is GitHub.

Comment: Probably this post will be useful: https://engineering.pivotal.io/post/faking_oauth_sso/
See Strategy#1